# Renaming a column created from a select statement (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table and accidentally created a column with the name `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(email_sends.created_ts))`

I am unable to select this column to rename it since it uses protected characters. Basically, I am asking for the proper way to escape this column name in mysql so that I can change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks to quote identifiers that contain special characters.  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it.
>
> [...]
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”)

Therefore, you can do something similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE foo CHANGE `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(email_sends.created_ts))` newname DATE;
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Given that I've quoted from the MySQL manual, it'd be a reasonable assumption that it might.. ;)